# How to fire off activity when myTime matches with android System time?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-alarms, android-calendar

I am trying to achieve a task. Here is what's happening. I first save a value in the shared preference in a string from first activity and pass that value to this activity below. Then in my second activity, I call that value. Then I take the current time of the android and convert it to string.

=====================================================

@Lazy Ninja: ***UPDATED PLEASE CHECK:*** okay. I got the timings to match Finally! Now just one last thing, how do I keep running this "if statement" in the background so even if the app is closed, the system keeps checking for those two values?

[image]

=====================================================

UPDATED CODE:

```
                Intent in = new Intent(Alarm.this, FajrAlarmRecieverActivity.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(Alarm.this, 2, in, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

                /*My Time from Shared Preference*/
                //SharedPreferences prfs = getSharedPreferences("customeAlarmTimes", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                //myTime = prfs.getString("Isha", "Isha");

                String myTime = "11:15";

                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm"); 
                Date date = formatter.parse(myTime); // You will need try/catch around this
                long millis = date.getTime();
                /*My Time from Shared Preference*/

                /*System Time*/
                Date today = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                String reportDate = new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm").format(today);
                Date swag = formatter.parse(reportDate);
                long currentTime= swag.getTime();

                Log.d("SystemTime", reportDate);
                Log.d("MyTime", myTime);
                Log.d("SystemTime in Millis", currentTime+"");
                Log.d("MyTime in Millis", millis+"");

                if(millis == currentTime){
                    SendNotification();
                    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
                }
                else if (millis > currentTime){
                    Toast mtoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAJR TIME > CURRENT TIME", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    mtoast.show();
                }
                else if (millis < currentTime){
                    Toast mtoast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAJR TIME < CURRENT TIME", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    mtoast.show();
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, if you want to fire at 3pm, and its 4 pm already it should fire at 4 pm tomorrow ?

Comment: Nope, if I want it to fire at 3pm, and its 4pm already then it should reschedule it for tomorrow at 3pm. :)

Comment: Yeah, sorry meant that ;)

Comment: Yeah, that and also firing off the alarm when the system time matches the saved preference value. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use repeating Alarm. It will handle the conditions for you
Try the following

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FajrAlarmRecieverActivity.class); 
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getActivity(Alarm.this, 0, i, 0);

// Get Time from your sharedpreferences
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour); // set　Fajr hour
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute); // set Fajr minute
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // set seconds  ( well no need for seconds)    
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

Dont forget to add FajrAlarmRecieverActivity in your manifest file.
After reading your comment just use set.
After the alarm fires, read from sharedPreferences and and set the alarm again.

EDIT
To get Current time

```
long currentTime= System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Get Time from your sharedPrefs, and convert it to milliseconds

```
if( sharedTimeInMillis < currentTime ){
   // your good stuff
}
```

Convert your String time to milliseconds

```
myTime = prfs.getString("Isha", "Isha");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm"); 
Date date = formatter.parse(myTime ); // You will need try/catch around this
long millis = date.getTime();
```

Comment: I tried that... that only fires off the alarm at the specific hour. I dont want that. I want it to match the saved value in my shared preference. If the saved value matched the android time, then it should fire off the alarm. Let's say my saved value from preference is: 10:54... So what I wanna do is keep checking for android's time and the moment android's time match this time which is 10:54. Fire off the alarm. :)

Comment: Do you keep updating the shared prefs value ?

Comment: The shared prefs value keep updating every 24 hours. :)

Comment: @LazyNinja: Now all I want to ask you is how to I compare the two times, the shared preference value and the time from android. I have like this: if(myTime == reportDate){//Good Stuff Here//};

The only problem with that it that it only checks it one time :( which means it doesn't keep on going. All I want to do now is compare these two times and keep them checking until they do compare. I want this to happen in the background so even if the app is closed, this activity can still check and compare the times and fire off...the alarm which will be inside it.

Comment: So is anyone able to lead me in that direction as to how I would compare myTime value with the local android time. And when it matches, it should fire off the alarm. Regardless if the app is open or closed. :)

Comment: Just convert both time to milliseconds and make the comparison.@ShawnKing I assume that you know how to get current time in millisecs

Comment: ^ Sorry to bother Lazy Ninja... I Looked around on stack overflow but so far the only thing I get is them converting String Date to milliseconds... however, I have string time... 

Do you mind show me the way? I have two strings at the moment. One String from the saved value. Another from the local android time. :)

Comment: @LazyNinja: Please Check my edit. For some reason, it didn't went off at the specified time because the two millis don't match.

Comment: @ShawnKing Why do you want to compare the times? Just set the AlarmManager and it will fire when the time comes, the system will handle that for you. Have you a good understanding of AlarmManager?

Comment: @LazyNinja: Ahh good question :p. Let me explain. You see I have a java file which generates the prayer times for: Fajr, Zuhar, Asr, Maghrib, Isha. Now they are based on sunset and sunrise which means every 24 hours they change by a minute or two. Now when those five times are displayed. I saved them in the values. one of them is "Isha". If we can get one them to work, the rest is pretty much copy/paste. So what I wanna do is keep checking the user's local time and the moment it matches one of those time, for example, the isha time. It should fire off the alarm. :)

Comment: @LazyNinja: Okay Finally! with your help, I was able to match up the times. Now all I need to know is how to run that "if statement" in the background so even if the app is closed, it will still check for the time. This is the last thing before I figure this awesmazing thing with yout help :)

Comment: For that you need a service. Instead of starting an activity start a service. By the way I am looking forward for your app. Hope it will help lots of people wake up for Fajr salat.